Нужна ли запятая перед «как со мной» в предложении «без меня всё будет так же, так же, как со мной»?
Помогите правильно расставить запятые, пожалуйста.

Без меня всё будет так же(,) так же(,) как со мной.


Есть случаи, когда перед союзом «как» нужно ставить запятую. Один из них: когда в главной части стоит указательное слово (так, такой, тот, столь). Поэтому в предложениях с конструкцией «так же как» должна стоять запятая. Пример: Она оделась на мероприятие так же, как я.

Без меня всё будет так же, так же, как со мной.
Как вариант:
Без меня всё будет так же — так же, как со мной.

Как вариант:
Без меня всё будет тАк же — так же как со мнОй.
Пояснение

Тире действительно нужно поставить из-за повтора слов, чтобы обозначить увеличенную паузу

Ударение при отсутствии расчленения запятой сложного союза так же как  уходит в конец фразы. Здесь важно подчеркнуть сопоставление слов: тАк же — так же как со мнОй.

Розенталь допускает обособление оборотов вида так же как в виде единого сочетания, если он имеет значение сопоставления: Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, так же как параллельная — без расчленения сложного союза;


Пример по теме  расчленения союза: Сегодня очень холодно, так же как осенью. Сравнить: Сегодня так же холодно, как осенью.

Сравним варианты:

Без меня всё будет так же, как со мной.
Без меня всё будет так же — так же(,) как со мной.
Какой смысл в однозначном повторении фразы? Тавтология или плеоназм получается. Это художественный повтор? Может быть и так, но мне такой повтор не показался выразительным. Все-таки желательно добавить что-то новое. И всего-то — убрать лишнюю запятую во втором предложении, чтобы не было двойного "тАк же — тАк же".
